# How to remove toolbar in Windows IoT?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

I'm working on a programm for RaspberryPi with Windows IoT core.
My IDE is Visual Studio 2019. I use C# and UWP for my programm.

Everytime i upload the code to the Raspberry i get an annoying toolbar.
It's not from my programm. It comes directly from Windows.
How can I deactivate it?

Please see the picture.
[picturetoolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AqS8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable this by unchecking the setting:

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML -> Show runtime tools in application

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick response. It works perfectly.  :)